# How to set up an expression in a macro in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86, macros, expression

I am attempting to define a macro that computes the expression:

> ```
> −(2+4)/X
> ```

I initally stored the value of the first number into `eax` and then I added `eax` together to get the multiplied by two.
From there though I think I am messing up the multiplied by four as well as the division and negation. The `shr eax, 1` is based off some reading I did for a better way to divide but I may have used it wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
addMultiply MACRO num1, num2
mov eax, num1
add eax, eax
add eax, num2
mov ebx, 2
xor eax, ebx
shr eax, 1
ENDM
```

Comment: `shr eax, 1` divides by 2 but you want to divide by `X`.  However, think about how shifts relate to multiplying by 4.

Comment: What's the point of using EBX here?  If you want to flip the 2nd bit of EAX, just use `xor eax, 2` with an immediate source, no need to `mov` a `2` into EBX.  Anyway, look at optimized compiler output (on   https://godbolt.org/) for an equivalent C function.  Your first 3 instructions make sense, but the last part bears no relationship to the expression you're trying to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `shr eax, N` is a better way to divide unsigned `eax` by **2<sup>N</sup>**
and `sar eax, N` is a better way to divide signed `eax` by **2<sup>N</sup>**,
but you need to divide by a common integer **X** in `num1`. You won't get away without `idiv`.

```
addMultiply MACRO X, Y 
mov eax, Y          ; EAX=Y
mov ecx, X          ; ECX=X
lea eax,[ecx+2*eax] ; EAX=X+2*Y
sal eax, 1          ; EAX=2X+4Y 
cdq                 ; EDX:EAX=2X+4Y
idiv ecx            ; EAX=(2X+4Y)/X; EDX=remainder            
neg eax             ; EAX=-(2X+4Y)/X
ENDM
```